# Spark context startup too slow

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running Apache Spark in standalone mode with the following code:

```
from __future__ import division
from pyspark import SparkContext
import sys
sc = SparkContext()
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

data = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
words = data.flatMap(lambda x: x.split())
word_cant = words.map(lambda x: (x,1))
total = words.count()

cant_by_word = word_cant.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
freq = cant_by_word.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]/total))
sortedFreq = freq.sortBy(lambda x: x[1], False)
out = freq.takeOrdered(5, lambda s: -1*s)
print('output', out)
```

Running time for this example is greater than 8 seconds, no matter how small the input. I've tried stopping the program just after creatintg the Spark 
Context and running time is around 5 seconds. This an example of a run were i used ptime to measure:

```
ptime python freq_words.py sample.txt

ptime 1.0 for Win32, Freeware - http://www.pc-tools.net/
Copyright(C) 2002, Jem Berkes <jberkes@pc-tools.net>

===  python freq_words.py sample.txt ===
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

('output', [(u'tiene', 0.06666666666666667), (u'este', 0.06666666666666667), (u'veces', 0.13333333333333333), (u'la', 0.13333333333333333), (u'texto', 0.13333333333333333)])

Execution time: 9.046 s

C:\Users\user\Desktop\test>SUCCESS: The process with PID 5620 (child process of PID 6092) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 6092 (child process of PID 5776) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 5776 (child process of PID 1440) has been terminated.
```

Is there a way to speed this up? or maybe reuse the spark context when running this a second time?

Answer (score 3):

Spark is heavy weight processing engine and it is not designed for low latency processing. Constant 8s ovherhead is really not an issue for a typical Spark job.

But to answer your question:

> a way to speed this up?

Don't use MS Windows. Spark, especially PySpark, has to use very inefficient logic to address limitation of the OS.